# get_posts() with custom post type does not work outside page.php

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have created a custom post type called "community", created a new post with a category (`cat id = 6`). I am using the following code:

```
$args = array (
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'community',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'category'    => 6
);
$communities = get_posts($args);
```

It worked perfectly inside my *page.php*. However, it's not working when I am trying the same inside *category.php* page, I am not getting the posts accurately! It's returning all the other posts.

Any idea?

Comment: Do not run custom queries in place of the main query on the category archive page. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is a filter-- `pre_get_posts` most likely-- being applied to the category archive and that that filter is written too broadly, and applies to all queries on the page instead of just the one it is intended for-- probably the main query. The correct solution would be to fix that filter, but I can't say exactly how without seeing the code. I'd guess you need to add `if(is_main_query()) {... }` but again, that is guessing.

You could remove the filter if you know what its callback is:

```
remove_filter('pre_get_posts','callback_name');
```

You would need that just before your query and you might need an `add_filter()` afterwards, depending on your page structure.

You [could also use](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_filters):

```
remove_all_filters( 'pre_get_posts` );
```

But that is really taking a sledge hammer to the problem.